# Writing Data to Google Sheets using Quasar (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, google-sheets, quasar-framework

I have a very small Quasar application that allows people to join a club online.  I want to be able to take their data and save it into a Google Sheet.  I really have no idea where to start.

Do I need to have the Google API installed in my Quasar Application? Do I need my application to be able to login to my Google Account?

I kinda need a Quasar/Google Sheet for dummies tutorial about how this works, and how to put it together.  I've been reading online about the parts but I'm not sure how to put them together.  Thanks for any info.

Comment: This [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) is a good start. Since Quasar/Vue is just JS in the end, all you need to do is to make a request to the Google APIs. You don't install it as such, but you need to create credentials for it within GCP (see quickstart), then your JS can use the credentials to make an authorized call to the Sheets API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After spending all day yesterday reading online, I was also thinking I probably just need to go with javascript. I'll check out that reference.